# TActionMainMenuBar and CustomTitleBar is having Font issue with RC file when DPI aware is PerMonitorV2

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I have defined the DPI setting below in CodeTree.dpproj file using the Manifest setting in Delphi.

worked fine in all the monitors when no **.RC** file is present but I have figured out the issue happens in case I'm having.RC file in our project gives blurry fonts with no color which is leading to distortion of UI.

If I remove/rename .RC file fonts look crisp and behave fine as per the DPI-aware setting given.

**If I create RC with the same name as .EXE**  - Fonts and Color issue as below
[image]

Can you help me if I am missing anything to add/override for the DPI awareness setting after adding RC file? I am expecting blank .RC should not create problems.

**After removing/renaming RC works fine:**
[image]

Comment: I suggest you could try to set default awareness with the application manifest. For more details, you could refer to the Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT
in the above problem, I am already using PerMonitorV2 awareness mode similar to the article you have shared.
The only problem is as soon as I add RC file with the same name as Exe to my project this creates font distortion whereas it works fine when an RC file is there with a different name. doesn't matter if the RC file is blank still issue is there. 
I need to know why RC file is creating DPI issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the IDE auto-generates a file with project name and .RC extension (i.e. *CodeTree.RC*), this interferes with your similar named file. Choosing a different name for your RC files solves the problem as you already found by yourself.

Comment: I have added this file (CodeTree.RC) manually to keep some details like version info of the assembly there is no file auto-generate by IDE with this name,  also can you help why this file is impacting the DPI settings of the application?

Comment: If there is no resource file created by the IDE, do you provide all DPI settings, too? It is not trivial to create a complete RC file like the IDE does.

Comment: DPI settings present in Option>Application>Manifest >AutoGenerate>
   Enable runtime Themes => true
   DPI => PerMonitorV2
 
I don't know how to put the above DPI settings in the RC file, Can you provide a sample RC for what you are suggesting?

Comment: Are you sure that the IDE does not create and link a manifest? Does your manifest also include the dependency to Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls version 6 and the compatibility settings for the different Windows versions? Can you show the content of your RC file? Can you show the manifest settings for the project?

Comment: You can download this project from the Embarcardo link, I have added a blank RC file to this to reproduce this issue. 
https://delphibydesign.com/wp-content/uploads/CustomTitleBars.zip